# Failed to connect to docker container running Postgres via pgbouncer

Tags: postgresql, docker, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

Trying to create connection pool using **pgbouncer**. Here is the `docker-compose.yml` file.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass

  pgbouncer:
    image: edoburu/pgbouncer
    environment:
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=pass
      - DB_HOST=db
      # - DB_NAME=test
      # for postgres:14 and above
      - AUTH_TYPE=scram-sha-256 
      - POOL_MODE=transaction
      - ADMIN_USERS=postgres,dbuser
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  pg_data:
```

These two containers are running fine. But but when I try to connect to **postgres** via **pgbouncer**, it throws an error:

```bash
$ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres 
Password for user postgres: 
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

In logs I see this:

```bash
compose-db-1         |  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
compose-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-03-29 02:19:45.445 UTC [1] WARNING C-0x7f3475c6f3a0: postgres/postgres@172.19.0.1:59276 pooler error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
compose-pgbouncer-1  | 2024-03-29 02:19:45.445 UTC [1] LOG S-0x7f3475c193c0: postgres/postgres@172.19.0.2:5432 closing because: login failed (age=0s)
```

What the issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem; I'm able to successfully connect using `psql` to the pgbouncer-hosted port. You're copying some configuration into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` but haven't shown us those files; could anything there be impacting the auth configuration?

Comment: @larsks I only have `docker-compose.yml` file. Which config you're taking about?

Comment: Never use a superuser as application user.

Comment: Your log file entries do not look complete.

Comment: You don't only have a `docker-compose.yml` file; you have a bind mount in your `volumes` section for `./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, which means you have some files in your `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory.

Comment: Your file works for me too.  It generates a log entry about the empty '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d' being ignored, but then proceeds as expected with authentication working.  Maybe you had a pre-existing pg_data directory which was already initialized and already had a different password.